# Can java only use ReentrantLock to guarantee non-violate variable become visible among thread

Tags: java

**The question is:** a++ operation is visible to other thread?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (; ; ) {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    //a++ operation is visible to other thread????
                    a++;
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: depends upon , "where variable - a is defined?"

Comment: variable a is a class static field,like this:public class Test2 { private static int a;}

Comment: If other threads want to use same variable -a , then, if variable is being used by this thread, then they can not access it until it release its lock. So, they will be in queue to use variable in future.

Answer (score 3):

Visibility is guaranteed only for threads that take the the same lock.

Comment: i know java key word volatile is implemented by using lock instruction，but how java lock implements it.

Comment: @jack synchronized uses a lock implemented by the JVM, optionally using a mutex OS lock and is much more heavyweight (and provides more functionality)

Answer (score 0):

Do forget about your code. Use this one:

```
AtomicInteger a = new AtomicInteger(0);
int one = a.incrementAndGet();
int two = a.incrementAndGet();
int three = a.incrementAndGet();
```